# Declare a string a variable in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables

My code has variables `mri1_tasks` and `mri2_tasks`. Is there a function to have python interpret `'mri%d_tasks'%num` (where `num` is equal to either 1 or 2) as the stored value of `mri1_tasks` or `mri2_tasks` based on the value of `num`?

Comment: Use a single list instead of multiple variables.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a list with both strings at separate indices and use the index as the switch?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two variables, you can store the variables in a dictionary, with variable name as the key.

```
vars = {
    'mri1_tasks': 0,
    'mri2_tasks': 1,
}

num = 1
print vars['mri%d_tasks'%num]
```